# How to prove divisibility implication.

Tags: divisibility, proof-explanation

If 11|(12i+3j) and 22|j then 11|i.

This is the implication.

Focusing on 22|j. If J is divisible by 22 that means its an even number and is also divisible by 11. Can I go from 22|j to 11|(j/2)?

I dont know what I should do after this point. Should I use Transability of Divisibility or Divisibility of Integer combinations to prove.

Comment: Yes, if $22\mid j$, $11\mid j$: if $j=22 k$, then $j=11\cdot(2k)$.

Comment: @Bernard If I can confirm $11|J$ then I can conclude that $11|3j$ then I can determine that $11|12i$ this is where I am stuck again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$11\mid12i+3j$ means there exists $l$ such that $12i+3j=11l$. If furthermore $j=22k$, then
$$12i=11l-3j=11(l-6j),$$
whence $i=12i-11i=11(l-6j-i)$.